# regex, is there something different about IsMatch

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am trying to find files which follow the pattern of "char 'h' followed by one or more digits" like this h0, h1, h22

but I am getting also "h22 cco" and hhh0

how to fix that

```
files = new List<String>((from file in files where Regex.IsMatch(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file), "h\\d+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline) select Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)));
```

Regards

Comment: I'd suggest looking up `^` and `$`, and for general C# use, using the `@` prefix on strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use beginning and end of line or string special char `^` and `$`, i.e.: `^h+\d+$`.

```
const string Pattern = @"^h+\d+$";
```

It will match string, which contains one or more `h` at beginning of string, then digit one or more repetitions. Example: `h0`, `h34`, `hh5`, `hhhh789`.

If you need only one `h` at beginning, use this regex: `^h\d+$`. It will match: `h0`, `h34`, `h789323`.

Comment: it removed "h22 cco" but I still have "hhh01" !!

Comment: @Costa, use `+` - one or more repetitions.

Comment: but what is ^  ? I guess start of the line :(

Comment: @Costa, `^` - means beginning of line or string

Comment: @polishchuk Why, I need only one h

Comment: @Costa, So use 2nd pattern, i.e.: `^h\d+$`

Answer (score 0):

The **^** means: Matches the starting position within the string. In line-based tools, it matches the starting position of any line.

I guess u need this pattern:

```
Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"\bh\d+\b", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

"\b" means **Word boundaries**